# No data displayed in Twitter Bootstrap Modal php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, symfony-1.4

I want to display page as a modal instead of redirecting. My problem is, I can display the table inside modal but none of the supposed data is in it.

Here is what I have so far:

**HTML:**

```
<td><a class="btn btn-small btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="<?php echo getApplicantDetailsModals($l['Applicants']['id'],$l['Applicants']['lastname'],$l['Applicants']['firstname']) ?>">Name here</a></td>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="memberModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="memberModalLabel">Borrower Last 5 Loans Details</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="ct"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using getApplicantDetailsModals as a helper that will point to the template.

**Helper:**

```
function getApplicantDetailsModals($id, $lastname, $firstname) {
$user = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser();
if($user->hasCredential('VIEW_APPLICANT')) {
    $controller = sfContext::getInstance()->getController();
    $url = $controller->genUrl(array(
            'module'=>'misc',
            'action'=>'applicant',
            'id'=>$id
        ));
    return "<span class='info'><a href='$url'>$lastname, $firstname</a></span>";
} else {
    return "$lastname, $firstname";
}
```

**Symfony 1.4 Action:**

```
public function executeApplicant(sfWebRequest $r) {
$this->applicant = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Loans')->findOneLoans($r->getParameter('id'));
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php include_component('misc','applicant')?>
<table>
<tr>
 <td>name</td>
</tr>
<?php foreach($applicant as $a):?>
<td><?php echo $a->name ?></td>
<?php endforeach ?>
</table
```

**More Javascript:**

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
     // var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
      var modal = $(this);
      var dataString = 'id' //+ recipient;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo url_for('misc/applicant') ?>",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                modal.find('.ct').html(data);
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });  
})
```

This is a working app until I decided to use modal, now it will only display my table minus the expected data inside in it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: do you have any error in the javascript console?

Comment: @RobertoNovelo .Nope.I see no errors

Comment: All I can think of to test what you are doing, is changing modal.find('.ct').html(data); for $('.ct').html(data);

Comment: @RobertNovelo I am calling table data via Doctrine 1.2 DQL.Maybe there's something wrong with my JavaScript/Ajax.

Comment: thats what I mean, changing modal.find('.ct').html(data); for $('.ct').html(data); is javascript.  Is the on show.bs.modal event fired? add a console.log line to see if it is (before the ajax line).